# Can I automate code re-execution if an error is raised?

Tags: python, automation

I have a program comprising multiple .py files in the same folder; I execute it by running one particular file in my IDE, Pycharm. (The file, let's call it `A.py`, calls a single `main()` method defined therein, so running the file just means running that method.) It's part of ongoing research, and even in the best-case scenario it take a long time to finish due to the computational complexity, so ideally I'd just hit run, do something else and check back later.

However, there's a problem:

- the program's behaviour depends on a remote server's reaction to a request;
- sometimes (increasingly often in the past few days), this results in an SSLError and an exit code 1;
- and, for the purposes of this question, we'll assume I can't remove this intermittent problem with edits to my own code.

So what I'd like to do, instead of manually restarting each time this happens, is set a finite allowable number of retries, wherein the exit code 1 is swallowed if encountered, leading to the next attempt.

It would be something like this in a second file, if you'll pardon the pseudocode:

```
from a import main

numtries, maxtries = 0, 10

while numtries < maxtries:

    ec = exitcode(main)

    if ec != 0: numtries += 1
```

Can something like this be done?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question, as what you describe is a Non-Unit test ( as there may be an SSL Dependency), as your code requires dependancies outside your control.

Can you re-write your Unit tests to only cover the code you can directly control ? Then move the SSL-Types to a higher-module based test strategy.

Regarding the pseudo code .... If you feel that 3 cracks at some function before you get the correct answer (you are going to try SSLException aren't you ?) then go for it....

But why does the SSL fail ? and should your software not handle that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch the exception. The return code is from the whole execution, but instead, you want something like:

```
retries = 0
while retries > limit:
    try:
        A.main()
    except SSLError:
        retries += 1
```

You could also do it in a shell script. Then you would use the return code 1 to check for success, as you first proposed. However, I would advise the first approach.